# Quickdialog does not build QpickerElement

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json, quickdialog

I'm using the `QuickDialog` framework. It's an awesome framework but I have a strange problem.
 I have a `JSON` that I got back from my `Webservice`. Everything is working, only it will not build the `QPickerElements`. I get the following warning in my console.

```
 Couldn't build element for type QPickerElement
```

But now the strange thing. When I paste the code in the demo of the framework. Everything works like it is supposed to...

This is how I load up the JSON in my app.

```
 NSString *jsonSample = data2.form;
 NSLog(@"JSON SAMPLE IS %@",jsonSample);
 id const parsedJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonSample dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
   QRootElement *root = [[QRootElement alloc] initWithJSON:parsedJson andData:nil];

  TestViewController *quickformController = (TestViewController *) [[TestViewController alloc] initWithRoot:root];
  [quickformController setScriptId:_event.eve_id];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:quickformController animated:YES];
```

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have the QuickDialog project embedded into yours as is the recommendation in quickdialog webpage, só, click on the quickdialog root project, then in target click in QuickDialog, in the right hand side select "Build Phases", add all .m (or whatever you want) into "Compiled Sources", then add the same .h into "Copy Headers"